# How to take a json string like this below to transform to dictionary?

Tags: ios, json, nsstring, nsdictionary

I got a json like this:

```
`{
   "_j_msgid" = 2404589949;
    aps =     {
        alert = "E\U519c\U901a";
        badge = 26;
        sound = "happy.caf";
   };
   data = "{title=\U901a\U77e5\U516c\U544a, pushId=15, pushType=NOTICECOL}";  // this line is my want.
}`
```

But, I use my method to take the json string to `dictionary`:

```
+ (NSDictionary *)dictionaryWithJsonString:(NSString *)jsonString {
    if (jsonString == nil) {
        return nil;
    }

NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError *err;
NSDictionary *dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData
                                                    options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                      error:&err];
if(err) {
    NSLog(@"json fail：%@",err);
    return nil;
}
return dic;
}
```

I failed, get a nil dictionary.

So, I convert the `data`'s `=` to `:`,then use `+ (NSDictionary *)dictionaryWithJsonString:(NSString *)jsonString` to transform the converted `json` string to dictionary, and I failed again.

Is there some useful method to transform this type `json` string to dictionary?

Comment: Please can you show your json string in string format as soon as possible?

Comment: Check my answer brother.I got it perfectly.

Comment: It seems more that what you got is the `-description` of a `NSDictionary` object than real JSON. From where are you exactly getting this?  So if you have that dictionary in a `NSDictionary` object (not a `NSString` one from `description`), you'll just have to do `NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithJsonString:thatDict[@"data"]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the solution and I got it.

Your json is above.That is the json response.Whatever when you convert JSON to string it should be

```
NSString *strJson = @"{\"_j_msgid\":\"2404589949\",\"aps\" : {\"alert\" :\"EU519cU901a\",\"badge\":\"26\",\"sound\":\"happy.caf\"},\"data\":{\"title\" :\"U901aU77e5U516cU544a\",\"pushId\":\"15\",\"pushType\":\"NOTICECOL\"}}";
```

When you convert into string you should add

> \"key\":\"value\"

If it is dictionary

> {\"key\":\"value\"}

If dictioanry is inside the array

> [\"response\":{\"key\":\"value\"}]

Then the coding

```
NSError *jsonError;
NSString *strJson = @"{\"_j_msgid\":\"2404589949\",\"aps\" : {\"alert\" :\"EU519cU901a\",\"badge\":\"26\",\"sound\":\"happy.caf\"},\"data\":{\"title\" :\"U901aU77e5U516cU544a\",\"pushId\":\"15\",\"pushType\":\"NOTICECOL\"}}";
NSData *objectData = [strJson dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectData
                                                     options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                       error:&jsonError];

NSLog(@"json is - %@",json);
```

The printed results are

```
json is - {
 "_j_msgid" = 2404589949;
 aps =     {
    alert = EU519cU901a;
    badge = 26;
    sound = "happy.caf";
 };
 data =     {
    pushId = 15;
    pushType = NOTICECOL;
    title = U901aU77e5U516cU544a;
 };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

your json string is wrong, please check it once, it should be like this

```
{
"_j_msgid" : 2404589949,
"aps" :     {
    "alert" : "E\\U519c\\U901a",
    "badge" : 26,
    "sound" : "happy.caf"
},
"data" : "{title=\\U901a%5CU77e5\\U516c%5CU544a, pushId=15, pushType=NOTICECOL}"}
```